# click on button to show and hide multiple words in one paragraph using Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have added one button in my web app. which is use full for users where users click on the button to show the right word on the paragraph.

for example "Lorem ipsum is dummy test." here TEST word is wrong, click on the 'Show Correct Answer' button to show the correct word after the wrong word, and again press button to hide correct word.

Here is my code for hide and show text but it is useful for only one word I need to apply in multiple words in one paragraph.

```js
function showhide() {
  var div = document.getElementById('newpost');
  div.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
```

```css
.hidden{display: none;}
.cans{background-color: red;}
```

```html
Question1:    Lorem ipsum dummy text <div id="newpost"  class="hidden cans">Answer1</div> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <div id="newpost"  class="hidden cans">Answer2</div> to make a type specimen book <div id="newpost"  class="hidden cans">Answer3</div>.

<br><br>

<button class="ans" id="button" onclick="showhide()">Show correct Answer</button>
```

Comment: `id` needs to be unique for all elements

Comment: Can we use same id multiple times in one paragraph?

Comment: No. id needs to be unique for every elements. to avoid issues. Its still not clear what you are trying to achieve !

Comment: Can we perform this in another way?

Comment: You still did not added => Perform what ?

Comment: I mean it is possible with the class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220072/discussion-between-raj-raj-and-alwayshelping).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery methods called .hide() or .show() to view or not your element.
All you need to do is set an id to the element that you want to hide or show ad when the button is called you can call a function similar to this:

```
function hide(){
    $("#idofyourelement").hide();  
}

function show(){
    $("#idofyourelement").show();  
}
```